# A simple question on $SU(2)$ gauge transformations in Wen's papers on projective symmetry group (PSG)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, gauge-symmetry

Recently I am studying the projective symmetry group (PSG) and the associated concept of quantum order first [proposed by prof.Wen](http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v65/i16/e165113).

In Wen's [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0375960102008083), see the last line of Eq.(8), the local SU(2) gauge transformation for spinor operators is deﬁned as $\psi_i\rightarrow G_i\psi_i$, where $\psi_i=(\psi_{1i},\psi_{2i})^T$ are fermionic operators and $G_i\in SU(2)$. Why we define it like this?

Since as we know, the Shcwinger fermion representation for spin-1/2 can be written as $\mathbf{S}_i=\frac{1}{4}tr(\Psi_i^\dagger\mathbf{\sigma}\Psi_i)$, where $\Psi_i=\begin{pmatrix}
 \psi_{1i} & -\psi_{2i}^\dagger \\
 \psi_{2i} & \psi_{1i}^\dagger
\end{pmatrix}$, and $G_i\Psi_i$ which is the same as the above transformation $\psi_i\rightarrow G_i\psi_i$ is in fact a spin rotation of $\mathbf{S}_i$, while $\Psi_iG_i$ does *not* change spin $\mathbf{S}_i$ at all.

So in Eq.(8), why we define the SU(2) gauge transformation as $G_i\Psi_i$ rather than $\Psi_iG_i$?

Answer (score 4):

a) For a rotation of axis $\vec n$ and angle $\theta$, the transformation for a spin $1/2$ representation is :

$$\psi \to e^{i \frac{\theta}{2}  \vec\sigma. \vec n}\psi = G(\vec n,\theta)\psi\tag{1}$$
where $\psi$ is a 2-component row complex spinor. Here $G(\vec n,\theta)$ is a member of $SU(2)$. The action of a matrix on a 2-component row object is always at the left of the object.

b) Beginning with : $\vec S=\frac{1}{4}tr(\Psi^\dagger \vec \sigma\Psi)$, suppose we have a transformation $\Psi \to \Psi G$. As you noticed, it would not change the value of $\vec S$, because :

$$tr(G^\dagger\Psi^\dagger \vec \sigma\Psi G)=tr(\Psi^\dagger \vec \sigma\Psi GG^\dagger) = tr(\Psi^\dagger \vec \sigma\Psi) \tag{2}$$

But $\vec S$ is a vector (it is in the fundamental or vectorial representation of $SO(3)$, or, if you prefer, in the adjoint representation of $SU(2)$), so it has to change under a rotation. So the transformation $\Psi \to \Psi G$ is non-valid and irrelevant.

Comment: @ Trimok, thanks for your answer. But I am still unclear that why we define the SU(2) gauge transformation as $G_i \Psi_i$ rather than  $\Psi_i G_i$? Maybe I'm not familiar with gauge theory.

Comment: The transformation law, for the spinor representation,  correspond to equation (1), so the transformation does not act on a matrix, but on a 2-row spinor. So, it is mandatory, in equation (1), that $G$ is at the left. Now, using $\Psi$,  is  a "trick" to present the spinor as a pseudo "matrix" to be used in a trace expression, it is not a fundamental presentation for the spinor representation. Now, you may consider the matrix $\Psi$ as $2 *2-$row spinors, so you may imagine that you apply $G$ on the first-column spinor, then on the second-column spinor, so $G$ must stay at the left, too.

Comment: @ Trimok, ok. And in the gauge transformation $\psi_i \rightarrow G_i \psi_i$, why we restrict $G_i$ belong to $SU(2)$ rather than $U(2)$? Thanks.

Comment: @K-boy : Spinor representations are some special representations of orthogonal groups $SO(p,q)$ which cannot be constructed with vectors or tensors (see Clifford algebra). If one is interesting with spinor representations of $SO(3)$, we have to look at the double cover of $SO(3)$, which is $SU(2)$ (this means that $S0(3) = SU(2)/Z_2$). So, we have to look at the representations of $SU(2)$. Each representation of $SU(2)$ is  labelled  by an integer or a half-integer. The representation corresponding to $1/2$ corresponds to a spinor representation. You may go further and considering the Lorentz

Comment: @K-boy : .....group $SO(3,1)$, wich has a double cover $SL(2,C)$. The representations of $SL(2,C)$ are labelled by $2$ numbers $(p,q)$ which can be integers or semi-integers. A left-handed spinor corresponds to the representation $(1/2,0)$, a right-handed spinor correspond to the representation $(0,1/2)$. They transform in the same way under rotations, but not with boosts.

Answer (score 1):

God, I just found that I made a very foolish misunderstanding of prof.Wen's paper. In fact, the operator $\psi_i=(\psi_{1i},\psi_{2i})^T=(f_{1i},f_{2i}^\dagger)^T$ and $\mathbf{S_i}=\frac{1}{2}f_i^\dagger\mathbf{\sigma}f_i$, but I misunderstood  $\mathbf{S_i}=\frac{1}{2}\psi_i^\dagger\mathbf{\sigma}\psi_i$ before(**Please see Eq.(8) in this paper http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v65/i16/e165113 at the very beginning**).

Now everything goes well. In fact, the $SU(2)$ gauge transformations $\psi_i \rightarrow G_i\psi_i$ are totally *equivalent* to $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
 f_{1i} & -f_{2i}^\dagger\\ 
f_{2i}  & f_{1i}^\dagger
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)\rightarrow \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
 f_{1i} & -f_{2i}^\dagger\\ 
f_{2i}  & f_{1i}^\dagger
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)G_i$. And the $SU(2)$ matrices being on the left or right depends on the notation of spinon operartors that you define, which is not the key point here.

Note: The operators $\psi_i$ that appear in all of Wen's papers on PSG in 2002 are *not* the direct annihilation operators for Schwinger-fermions $f_i$, so please be very careful!